# How can I get the first two words in a sentence using java in android studio?

Tags: java, android

Let's say a person's name has three words, I just wanna show the first two words using a TextView.
What's the easiest way to do that?

```
String name = "abc def geh ijk";

String twoWordsName;
```

Comment: Add some examples.

Comment: I just want "abc def" in String twoWordsName.

Answer (score 3):

Or String.substring()

```
String twoWordsName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' ', name.indexOf(' ')+1));
```

Comment: Perfect; but in this condition, If there's a single word it'll crash the app. so better check length of sentence.

Answer (score 2):

do this:

```
String name = "abc def geh ijk";
String[] result = name.split("\\s+");
```

first two words:

```
result[0] is "abc"
result[1] is "def"
```

Comment: Good tip to know: check the size of the string array first before trying to retrieve any of its items

Comment: I can use this, but this won't be efficient in the case of long paragraphs (500 words) where I just want the first two words.

Comment: you can use name.substring(0, 20) to get shorter string;

Comment: @Ehsanmsz unless he knows how long each word is, i wouldnt do that

Answer (score 0):

using split()

```
String[] words = name.trim().split(" ")
if(words.length >= 2) {
    String twoWordsName = words[0] + " " + words[1]
    textView.setTexttwoWordsName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get each of the words In a string
You can use string tokenizer

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence";
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
String word ="";
while(t.hasMoreTokens())
{
word = t.nextToken();
System.out.println(word);
}
```